# How to apply other bootstrap and html properties to Django form fields

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-forms, django-templates

```
{{ form.firstname|as_crispy_field}}
```

I want to know how further I can add bootstrap classes to this Django form field and also I want to add a placeholder

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [FormHelper](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html#formhelper) to add `css classes` and `placeholders` to your form. For example if you have the form:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['pub_date', 'headline', 'content', 'reporter']
```

Add `init` function to it:

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Form

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    [...]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('pub_date', css_class="Your css class" placeholder='Pub Date ...', ),
            [...]
    )
```

check [Layouts](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html) for more informations.